# Does Acquia Dev Desktop allow 2 or more local sites using different core versions?

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

The goal was to assemble a local version of a live Drupal 7 site, plus a new installation of Drupal 8 which would become the upgraded version of the Drupal 7 site. But whether I create the Drupal 7 or the Drupal 8 version first in Dev Desktop 2 ("DD"), it seems not to allow the 2nd version in a different Drupal version. Despite different database names clearly defined in DD, a second site added is always being confused as associated with the 1st site's database. What needs to be done differently, if indeed it should be possible to have these 2 versions coexisting in the DD sites list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Aqcuia Dev Desktop 2 allows you to work on Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 sites together. I have multiple 7 and 8 sites built on Dev Desktop 2.  **I do however keep the codebases for them in different directories.** My D7 production copy sites are not kept in the Sites/devdesktop folder. Also, they are all imported to Acquia, not generated by Acquia. The only "crossing of wires" I ever got was in cloning composer built 8 sites, and those were actually Acquia generated sites.

My D8 composer sites, though they are in Sites/devdesktop are also imported, not generated by Aquia, as I am using this composer based Drupal 8 project: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

Drupal has docs on it here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-template-for-drupal-projects

There is also a short YouTube video on how to install it with composer here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IhWAegz8glk

To import a site rather than letting Acquia build it, do the following:

- click the + button on the DD UI panel and select "import local Drupal site".
- Select the directory of the  codebase
- name the site,
- choose php version.
- create a new database.
- Click OK.

You can then use backup and migrate to restore your D7 data in your case.

I'm honestly not sure if it's the importing feature itself, or the separate directories that is doing the trick, but it has been working great for me!

Let us know!

Comment: Thanks much for those suggestions! At this point, I have had some new success but it is incomplete. I have not yet understood how and why to use Composer. But I did get both the old D7 site and the new (currently empty) D8 site listed as enabled in Dev Desktop, without "crossed wires." The problem now is, the D8 site's URL (from DD) is opening "in maintenance mode" and I can't get a login screen to change that. The D7 site is not configured to display a login screen, but adding "/user" to the URL fixes that. This same method does *not* work in the D8 site. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If it's installed correctly, you should be logged in on your first visit. Hard to say without looking at it.

Comment: Composer is in short a dependency manager that when it installs modules for example, it also installs all libraries and other modules that module depends on. There's a little headache in getting it installed but it will save you TONS of time down the road. The file directory structure on a composer built site is also different and preferred.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md